# Visual Studio 2010 Watch Window?

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on a C++ code, and this is what I have in Visual Studio 2010 watch window:

[image]

I just need to understand what it means when File_Service is in [] and how to access it in my code.
When I add it to the watch window, Visual studio adds it like this: `{,,Simulator.exe}*(File_Service*){*}exe`
Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets in this case mean that the dynamic type of variable `exe` is `File_Service`. That is, your `exe` variable, of type unknown to me, is pointing on an object of type `File_Service`. Assuming `exe` is of type `Executable`, which `File_Service` inherits from, under that [File_Service] you'll find the variables that have been defined in `File_Service`.

When adding the expression in the square brackets as a member to watch, you're basically instructing the debugger to cast `exe` into a `File_Service`. This is fine in this case, but if `exe` will point on a different kind of `Executable`, that weird-looking expression won't show you anything (you can't downcast an `Executable` object, say, to a `File_Service`).

Comment: Thank you for your help Eran. If that is the case, why I can not access File_Service variables using this: ((File_Service*)exe)-> 
and how this one is interpreted: {,,Simulator.exe}*(File_Service*){*}exe Why not just (File_Service*)exe ?

Comment: The reason this is not trivial is that the debugger is not a compiler - it doesn't have all the information regarding data types. I guess that when certain type information is needed, you must specify the module (Simulator.exe in this case). I wasn't able to find any formal documentation, but check out [this](http://m.c-plusplus.de/50940), under "Casting In The Debugger". Bottom line, I guess it's just a technical limitation you have to make do with...